# Ionic Iphone Design Issue

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone, ionic-framework

While building the ionic application. I wrote out a bunch of css. It works and looks good on an android, but when I tested it on an IOS platform (iphone 6) the design wasn't the same. Thus, I changed the design and added the ".platfrom-ios". Then today, i tested the application on an iPhone 5 and the design wasn't similar. Everything slanted to the right.

Can someone please explain why there's such a drastic change in the design?

Comment: can you explain the design differences? The only problem between Android and iOS here was solved by adding a padding-top of 10px on views that does not have a header bar